# Input encoding : accepting UTF-8

Tags: encoding, powershell

I need to get output of native application under PowerShell. The problem is, output is encoded with UTF-8 (no BOM), which PowerShell does not recognize and just converts those funky UTF chars directly into Unicode.

I've found PowerShell has `$OutputEncoding` variable, but it does not seem to affect input data.

Good ol' iconv is of no help either, since this unnecessary UTF8-as-if-ASCII => Unicode conversion takes place before the next pipeline member acquires data.

Comment: Can you give a sample of what your trying to achieve ? Answer might be different if you're using files or if you just want to show some data on screen...

Comment: How could I possibly make it more clear? "./program-that-outputs-utf8 > 1.txt" -- does not work, "./program-that-outputs-utf8 | out-file -enc utf8 1.txt" -- does not work either. The exact program and exact data will tell you nothing.

Comment: That comment makes it more clear.

Comment: I think you meant "UTF8-as-if-current-codepage". ASCII only defines chars up to 0x7F. and UTF-8 is a strict superset. All non-ASCII characters in UTF-8 are represented as a sequence of bytes all >=0x80.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see the issue now with the program below (stdout.cpp - cl stdout.cpp):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char bytes[] = { 0x41, 0x53, 0x43, 0x49, 
                     0x49, 0x20, 0x6F, 0x75, 
                     0x74, 0x70, 0x75, 0x74,
                     0xE1, 0xBE, 0xB9};

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", bytes[i]);
    }                
}
```

And running that through `| Out-File -enc UTF8 foo.txt` gives the gibberish:

```
PS> fhex foo.txt

Address:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F ASCII
-------- ----------------------------------------------- ----------------
00000000 EF BB BF 41 53 43 49 49 20 6F 75 74 70 75 74 0D ...ASCII output.
00000010 9F E2 95 9B E2 95 A3 0D 0A                      .........
```

Note that fhex is a [PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com) utility.

*UPDATE:* Figured out how to get this to work:

```
$enc = [Console]::OutputEncoding
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [text.encoding]::utf8
.\stdout.exe | out-file fubar3.txt -enc utf8
fhex .\fubar3.txt

Address:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F ASCII
-------- ----------------------------------------------- ----------------
00000000 EF BB BF 41 53 43 49 49 20 6F 75 74 70 75 74 E1 ...ASCII output.
00000010 BE B9 0D 0A                                     ....

[Console]::OutputEncoding = $enc
```

Comment: How simple :) This example shows that in some cases one really needs to know .NET. Just posh knowledge is not enough...

Answer (score 0):

Probabry you need to execute "chcp 65001" (after modifying powershell.exe's font).
This command is available with PSISE.

Answer (score -2):

If your goal is to process data from your native command in powershell, you may try

```
./program-that-outputs-utf8 > temp.txt
get-content temp.txt -Encoding utf8 | (do_whatever)
```

Comment: This does not work. Look, initally powershell decodes all data from program-that-outputs-utf8 as if it were ASCII, effectively giving UTF gibberish (and not real characters that this gibberish represents) in _UNICODE_ strings. Then, if I use ">" operator, it will encode _THAT_ gibberish in UTF-16.